# How to enforce that a new entry can only be added to a table if one of its column values exists in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

- A: id, email, ... (email can have duplicates)
- B: id, email, ... (email is unique)

I want to only allow new entries in B where the email already exists in A.

Is there some way to do this via FKs or would I need some kind of trigger?

Answer (score 1):

You can add foreign key constraint on the Table B on this Email column, so that it will maintain the integrity.

```
ALTER TABLE B ADD CONSTRAINT fk_email
FOREIGN KEY ( EMAIL ) REFERENCES A ( EMAIL );
```

Comment: I thought foreign keys need to reference a primary or unique column

Comment: Yes, email column should be primary or unique key on that table, try to add unique constrain on EMAIL column of Table A, so that you can add FK constraint.

Comment: It is not unique or primary on table A

Comment: there can be duplicate emails in table A

Comment: Then, you should go for Trigger. As mysql doesn't allow "Stored functions and user-defined functions are not permitted." and "Sub-queries are not permitted."

Answer (score 1):

The unique emails should be stored in a separate table `X`:

```
CREATE TABLE X (email VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);
```

or, better:

```
CREATE TABLE X (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE);
```

Then, both tables `A` and `B` should have a column `email` or `email_id` referencing either the `email` or the `id` of the table `X`:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES X(email));
CREATE TABLE B (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES X(email));
```

or:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email_id INTEGER REFERENCES X(id));
CREATE TABLE B (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, email_id INTEGER REFERENCES X(id));
```